# Json object condition

Tags: jquery, json

i would like to create a Json object using an AND condition (i dont know if its possible). I put the unfinished code that i've by the moment.

```
var parameters = {
                Title : "hello",
                Text : "world",
                Question : //if two checkboxes are checked then true else false.
}
```

About the two checkboxes checked i was thinking to use this:

```
$('.checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('.checkbox2').is(':checked')
```

What i would like to avoid is to put an if like

```
//if checkboxes are checked
//{
//create the json object of type 1
//}
//else
//{
//create the json object of type 2
//}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you just tried it? Btw. this is **not** a JSON object. It is a normal JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a boolean would be ok:

```
var parameters = {
            Title : "hello",
            Text : "world",
            Question : $('.checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('.checkbox2').is(':checked')
}
```

This will create a regular JavaScript object which you can manipulate like any other object, e.g.,

```
parameters.Question = <newTrueOrFalseToSet>;
```

Or even:

```
parameters["Question"] = <newTrueOrFalseToSet>;
```

---

According to the [JSON definition](http://www.json.org/), the resulting JSON should look like:

```
{
    "Title": "hello",
    "Text": "world",
    "Question": true
}
```